# ReferenceError: Vue is not defined while using shallowMount

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, babel-jest

I am working on vue project and while doing unit testing using jest, I am getting following error for shallowMount:

```
ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

    > 1 | import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
        | ^
      2 | import About from '@/views/About.vue';
```

Following are my devDependencies from package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.5",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^5.0.6",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/compiler-dom": "^3.2.37",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "^28.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.1",
    "cypress": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint": "^8.17.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vuejs-accessibility": "^1.1.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^28.1.1",
    "typescript": "~3.9.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "~2.3.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-tailwind": "~3.0.0",
    "vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.1",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0"
  },
```

Following is my unit test code:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import About from '@/views/About.vue';

describe('About.vue', () => {
  test('renders inner text', () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-bitwise
    const wrapper = shallowMount(About);

    expect(wrapper.text()).toContain('about');
  });
});
```

Following is my Component code:

```
<template>
  <div class='about'>
    <h1>This is an about page</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default { name: 'about' };
</script>
```

Just wonder if I am doing something wrong with unit test or the component code or does the jest and other supporting libraries require version upgrade/downgrade?

based on comment 1:
Following are the dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.2",
    "@vee-validate/rules": "^4.1.17",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "firebase": "^8.2.7",
    "howler": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2",
    "vee-validate": "^4.1.18",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.0.0-rc.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
```

Comment: The error means that some dep relies on Vue 2 instead of 3, but this is not confirmed by devDependencies. What are regular `dependencies`? Why is vue3-jest alpha? You should avoid such deps, unless you're certain that you know what you're doing.

Comment: I added the dependencies in the post above. The vue3-jest alpha is because I tried updating all the json packages. Let me try and downgrading it to a stable version and see how it goes.